# How to watch for external slot changes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-component

I want to react to external slot changes. In actual HTMLSlotElements I have [`slotchange` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event) for that but it seems like that's not how that works in Vue 3. How can I watch my slot and react to any new elements being slotted?

This is what I tried:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSlots } from 'vue';

const slots = useSlots();

function handleSlotChange() {
  console.log('The slotted content has changed to ', slots.foo?.()[0]);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="foo" @slotchange="handleSlotChange"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: slot in vuejs are not the same as native slots in HTML

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yeah, I had to learn that the hard way :/

Comment: The vue slot doesn't have events, What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'm sorry, I am not sure how to answer that besides quoting the question itself: "Watch my slot and react to any new elements being slotted"?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim If you want more context: I am building a component library that allows the user to slot elements. These slotted elements then need to be enriched with attributes.

Comment: This is just off the top of my head, but perhaps you could use `this.$slots` (if that still exists in Vue 3, I forget) and use `watch` on it. Just a thought.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown `this.$slots` still exists in Vue 3 but it's not valid in script setup syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Vue's slots are not real slots we can't use Vue-internal tools to react to slot changes. Vue's compatibility layer prevents that. Instead, we can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
let observer: MutationObserver;

onMounted(() => {
  const el = document.querySelector('el-to-observe');
  const getSlotContent = () => el.querySelector('[slot]')?.tagName || 'Nothing';
  const callback = () => console.log(getSlotContent() + ' was slotted');

  observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(el, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  });
});

onUnmounted(() => observer?.disconnect());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `slot` element doesn't accept events, but you could use `@vnodeUpdated` event in the element that wraps the slot to watch the changes  :

```html
<template>
  <div @vnodeUpdated="handleSlotChange">
    <slot name="foo"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

the `vnodeUpdated` event handler has the current element as parameter which has `dynamicChildren` as property which refers to the elements passed as slots.

Or as @matthew-e-brown said in comments try to use the watch with slots :

```js
import { useSlots,watch } from 'vue';

const slots = useSlots();

watch(()=>slots.foo(),(v)=>{
  console.log('slots changed')
  },{
    deep:true
})
```

Comment: This events should be in the wrapper element, it will not work with slot element

Comment: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__eNp9Urtu20AQ/JXNpaAESCTSKpLiwI3TpAlSBLiGJpcSHd4Dd0emIFjkL9LlF/MJmTtShiwDbojlzu7szc6O4rO1+dCz2Im9r1xrA3kOvT1KTdQqa1yg0XEzUeOMogylmdQLcG+UXfJ5EX8iE2CiymgfKLAPBzSvshhla6n3xTwE9PgJrGxXBk7D9pEgRYgvCL1vjFmSSD/2IRhNd1XXVj8PUqQB2QN3ncmkOD60G/qSKfKdCYFr+vf3z28ax1g1Tfti7r6MKF5OT+9HeJUXGzEL3arS5k/eaGxpjNVyAbwUO0qZmIP4+C/FOQTrd0Xhmypu5Mnnxp0KRLnrdWgV5+zV9tGZX54diKXYXHEUSA7sto51zY7dW5w3pa94I+0k9QQpF39unaau1Ke4S5RD/8Vz6j1/wx79huAgXfv/MZo

Comment: 3Oxw37enwXLxaA5whfAPrADBdwFeTZxGESN30ugotjDyXuu5S5z3CE6/W8zaX3nwou57BkP1g/y7OhZa3Tuj84RjJ4P0n+P78hGg+oFRStwPdDdrU/N3WaKwh/fYZaRHpSKI+0qViVOESAWA8csvNgOzmZKb/bLglSg==

Comment: Please concatenate the two comment to get the url :)

Comment: What about `vnodeMounted` event?

Comment: It should rerender. Do you mean component lifecycle hooks by *the render lifecycle hook*